# installing latest matplotlib version with pypi

Tags: matplotlib, easy-install, pip

In some way this question was already asked ... so accept my apology ...

I am trying to install the latest version of matplotlib from here:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.0.1

I know I can download the sorce, untar and compile it, but I was to install it on many machines, and pip should be a bliss.

So, I did easy_install pip, and here the output I am getting with with both tools:

```
$ sudo easy_install "matplotlib==1.0.1"

install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for matplotlib==1.0.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
Reading http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/
No local packages or download links found for matplotlib==1.0.1
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('matplotlib==1.0.1')
```

or with pip:

```
$ pip install matplotlib==1.0.1
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib==1.0.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==1.0.1 (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for matplotlib==1.0.1
Storing complete log in /home/oz/.pip/pip.log
```

Insights and suggestions will be mostly welcomed ...

Oz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pip install -f  http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz  matplotlib
```

from here:
[Why does pip install matplotlib version 0.91.1 when PyPi shows version 1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555551/why-does-pip-install-matplotlib-version-0-91-1-when-pypi-shows-version-1-0-0)

sorry ...

Comment: regularly check updates in http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib + you can get pre-compiled libraries in http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/