# Pip doesn't install latest available version from pypi (argparse in this case)

Tags: python, macos, pip, argparse, pypi

### The problem

I worked on some python projects lately and had lots of problems with `pip` not installing the latest versions of some requirements. I am on `osx` and and I used [brew](http://brew.sh/) to install `Python 2.7.6`. In the project I'm working on, we simply install requirements like this:

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In the current case, I needed to install `argparse==1.2.1`. This is the actual latest version shown [on the pypi website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse)

Here's my output

```text
Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 1.0.1, 1.0, 1.1)
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
```

I had similar problems with different kinds of requirements such as `matplotlib` which I installed manually as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781684/1092815).

As you can see, pip on my mac only has those argparse versions: `0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 1.0.1, 1.0, 1.1`

### Attempts to fix

I tried reinstalling python with `brew reinstall python`, then also tried to reinstall all of my installed python packages with some `xargs` *magic*:

```bash
pip freeze | xargs -I {} pip install {} --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

While trying to reinstall everything, I had trouble with most of the packages: `error: invalid command 'egg_info'`. I figured out I had an old `setuptools` so I ran this to upgrade:

```bash
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and I could now reinstall everything, but still, same problem with `argparse`.

I asked a friend with a freshly installed osx to `pip install argparse` and he got `1.1` So I've setup a `precise32` [vagrant box](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for a clean ubuntu install with `python-dev` + `libevent-dev` and had no trouble at all installing `argparse==1.2.1`.

### Workaround

To continue working on the project, I installed argparse 1.1 on macOS and it seems to work fine at the moment for what I'm working on.

### Questions

1. Is-there any reason why I'm not getting the latest versions shown on pypi?
   Sounds like not all the libs on pypi are available for osx.
2. Is there a way to know version availability for different os?

Comment: What does `pip install -vv --no-install argparse` say?

Comment: `argparse` comes standard in `Python2.7`. While the `pypy` version number is `1.2.1`, its last changed date was 2011.  So it is not ahead of the latest Python release.

Comment: @hpaulj my `argparse.__version__` returns `'1.1'` in Python 2.7.6, not sure if this is the same version number though

Comment: Don't worry about that `1.1`.  Since it is part of the standard library that number isn't changing anymore.

Comment: @PeterGibson `pip install -vv --no-install argparse` says:
`DEPRECATION: '--no-install' and '--no-download are deprecated. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906. Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` I've tested with a vagrant and even thought the version of argparse installed is 1.2.1, argparse.__version__ returns `1.1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this line is the key:

> Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).

When I install argparse here I get

> You are installing an externally hosted file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing externally hosted files.
>
> Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB): 69kB downloaded

So you have a newer version of pip that is disallowing externally hosted files by default

Comment: I am using a recent version of pip:`pip 1.5.2 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)` Indeed, I always get that `--allow-external` message. I guess some developers will need to move their sources to pypi

Answer (score 9):

Here's the command I used to install argparse using pip 1.5.4:

```bash
pip install --allow-all-external argparse==1.2.1
```

Comment: So was the resulting `argparse` file any different from the standard one (2.7+)?

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` `1.1` seems to be the same as `1.2.1` as shown on this output:

```python
vagrant@precise32:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>> argparse.__version__
'1.1'
>>> quit()
vagrant@precise32:~$ pip freeze | grep argparse
argparse==1.2.1
```

I tried to use `--allow-external` on osx and the requirement needs to be placed **after** `--allow-external` flag, not before. Here's a valid command to install `argparse` and allowing externally hosted files with `pip` for Python2.7:

```bash
pip install --allow-external argparse --upgrade
```

```text
argparse an externally hosted file and may be unreliable
Downloading/unpacking argparse from http://argparse.googlecode.com/files/argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz#md5=2fbef8cb61e506c706957ab6e135840c
  Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB): 69kB downloaded
```

As pointed out by Peter, latest version of pip `default to disallowing externally hosted files`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21868684/3) to the question [Pip doesn't install latest available version from pypi (argparse in this case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868684/pip-doesnt-install-latest-available-version-from-pypi-argparse-in-this-case) by the OP [GabLeRoux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092815/gableroux) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>