# What is the prefered way to pip install from external sources

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Searching for a solution of anothe problem, I found some usefull hints about pip's parameters "--allow-external" and "--allow-all-external". I did not really get the difference but saw that both are deprecated "due to changes in the repository protocol".

What is the new/ prefered way to install packages and versions that are not available by default? -- Or does pip now allows external by default? 
I couldn't find any hint at the pip help or at stackoverflow.

Comment: what do you mean by "external"? from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)?

Comment: I am not quite sure. Here is where I came across it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868684/pip-doesnt-install-latest-available-version-from-pypi-argparse-in-this-case

Comment: I'm trying to get the pandapower tutorial working but they use features that aren't implemented in the latest version I get from pip. That question seamed to fit but the answers are depricated and don't work for me - so I guess there must be a not depricated way to do what the now depricated way(s) did for some time