# Why isn't pip installing the latest version of a package, even when a newer version is on PyPI?

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to upgrade to the latest version of a package I had installed with `pip`, but for some reason it won't get the latest version. I've tried uninstalling the package in question, or even reinstalling `pip` entirely, but it still refuses to get the latest version from PyPI. When I try to pin the package version (e.g. `pip install package==0.10.0`) it says that it "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package==0.10.0 (from versions: ...)"

`pip search package` even acknowledges that the installed version isn't the latest, labeling the two versions for me.

I've seen other questions with [external files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21868684/3551604) or [local versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617136/3551604), but I've tried the respective solutions (`--allow-external` doesn't exist anymore, and `--no-cache-dir` doesn't help) and I'm still stuck on the older version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I was trying to upgrade [Quart.](https://pypi.org/project/Quart/) Maybe other packages have something else going on.*

In this particular case, Quart had dropped support for Python 3.6 (the version I had installed) and only supported 3.7 or later. (This was a fairly recent change to the project, so I just didn't see the news.)

However, when attempting to install a package only supported by a later Python, `pip` doesn't really explain why it couldn't find a version to satisfy the requirement - instead, it just lists all the versions that should work with the current Python, without indicating that more exist and just can't be installed.

The only real options to fix are:

- Update your Python to meet the package's requirements
- Ask/help the maintainer to backport the package to the version you have.