# Python - installing matplotlib latest version on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, installation, pip

I'm currently running Matplotlib 0.99.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

I would like to upgrade Matplotlib to version 1.1.0.  I have tried following the 
[instructions](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#installing-from-source) at SourceForge, which didn't seem to do anything (IPython still thinks I have version 0.99.1.1).

I have tried searching for how to do this another way but, being relatively new to Linux, am a little confused what I need to do now.  I have tried a few suggestions on the forums but still I cannot seem to install Matplotlib-1.1.0

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555551/why-does-pip-install-matplotlib-version-0-91-1-when-pypi-shows-version-1-0-0) for example doesn't seem to work for me (pip complains of an "Unknown or unsupported command 'install'").

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless my memory fails me completely, I followed the build from source instructions you link to on two Lucid systems of mine. These instructions, to be precise:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#installing-from-source

Worked like a charm, after I remembered to do `python setup.py install`. And, yes,prior to the install, I removed the `0.99` matplotlib via synaptic. Did you try removing the older version first?

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/matplotlib

There is a section for binary builds, just grab the appropriate package for your system architecture and dpkg -i the_package_name.deb

Comment: Looks good, but there are a lot of dependencies I keep needing to install.  Is there a way to have these installed automatically?

Comment: Change your /etc/apt/sources.list to at least oneric and apt-get dist-upgrade!  Optionally build from source, but then you will have the dependency problems. This is the caveat to using LTS or any versioned-release distro.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong with my system, but the issue resolved itself.  Either one of the procedures I followed while searching for an answer worked, or the build from source instruction worked.

Perhaps my computer just took a while to realise I did in fact have the newest version installed.

For future reference, I would follow the install from source instructions on the matplotlib site at SourceForge, noting the answer by Zhenya.